# javascript/jquery not working in cakePhp view

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

This is a noob/novice problem: I am not able to get javascript/jquery to work in a cakePhp view.

A `subnav.ctp` element is included in `index.ctp`

subnav.ctp has the following:

```
<?php
    $script = <<<JS
        $("#test-open").click( function() {
          alert("test");
}); 
JS;
?>
```

and of course, at the end of the element `$this->Js->buffer($script)` and `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();` is included in the layout.

The code output, when I do a view source on the final page, seems to be correctly adding the js at the end of the html before the body ends

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test-open").click( function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

The jquery library is correctly included. This same code when I include in my external `core.js` works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: check your console for js errors

Comment: yes @AD7six there are errors, I'll spend some time understanding them.

Comment: @AD7six thank you for the insight, it seems the external js is throwing errors, which is somehow preventing my document.ready methods from executing.

Comment: @halfer thanks! but I had solved the issue. on an unrelated note, I'm trying to use $_SERVER to set my aws secret keys in cakephp. any advice there :P

Comment: I'm brand new to AWS, so sadly no - but do ask a new question on that if necessary. If you can add an answer below (and accept it when the system permits) that would be great, as the solution may be of interest to future readers (and it takes the question out of unanswered lists too).